# How do i have my script execute one more command after a previous command returns a non-zero value before it is aborted?

Tags: perl, command, exit

I have a shell script that calls on a Perl script to do some file processing. The Perl scripts exits with either a zero or one value. I have the Unix `set -e` command at the beginning of my script to abort the script if the Perl script exits with a value of one. I was just wondering if there is any command in Unix that I can use that would execute one command before the script is aborted if the Perl script exits with a one value? Essentially, I want the script to send me an email stating whether the Perl script ran successfully. My code looks like this right now:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function email_success {
#Some code for the email 
}

function email_fail {
#Some code for the email
}

usr/bin/perl perlscript.pl

if [$? -eq 0]; then 
 email_success
else 
 email_fail
fi 

#More commands to be executed if its successful
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `set -e` and add an exit to your `if` fail branch. If you want that behavior for the rest of the script add the `set -e` after the email call.

Comment: May this be elaborated more? Say, how to add exit in if branch in above example? What should be inside if condition?

Answer (score 1):

Use `set -e`

You can write:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# function email_success {...}

# function email_fail { ... }

if /usr/bin/perl perlscript.pl; then
  email_success
else
  email_fail
  exit 1
fi

#More commands to be executed if its successful
```

**Explanation**:

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) says:

> `-e` Exit immediately if a pipeline, which may consist of a single simple command, returns a non-zero status. The shell **does not exit** if the command that fails is part of the test in an `if` statement.

[Conditional Constructs (if)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> The syntax of the if command is
>
> ```
> if test-commands; then
>   consequent-commands;
> [elif more-test-commands; then
>   more-consequents;]
> [else alternate-consequents;]
>   fi
> ```
>
> The test-commands list is executed, and if its return status is zero, the consequent-commands list is executed. If ‘else alternate-consequents’ is present, and the final command in the final if or elif clause has a non-zero exit status, then alternate-consequents is executed.

See also: [Use the Unofficial Bash Strict Mode (Unless You Looove Debugging)](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/)